# Cocoa Client and Netty server

Tags: ios, cocoa, netty

I am building a mobile application, our backend server for realtime communication is in Netty. So when i am developing an Android client i don't have problem. But when we are developing IOS app, will that create any issues? (we yet to start with IOS). I am new to Netty and Cocoa, so can any one help me on this? I could understand sending streams over TCP can be done by Cocoa. But my main concern is, ByteBuf wrapper is used in java server and client. My understanding is ByteBuf is a special wrapper. How to read/write ByteBuf data from Cocoa?

Thanks